# Помогите разбить число

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6, python-2.7

мне нужно, чтобы число разбилось, и сравнилось. Например: Возьмём число 262, нужно, чтобы Python сравнил все цифры внутри этого числа (2<6, 6>2 и тд.) и если будут одинаковые числа (2==2), Python должен вывести слово 'YES'.

Входные данные: `262`

Выходные данные: `'YES'`

Я уже 2 часа потратил на это, и ничего годного не смог придумать. Я пытался идти через For. И делить тем самым число ( a=212, a%10) Но нужны всё время новые переменые, чтобы записывать туда число. А конкретно сколько перемных нужно не известно. Там может попасться любое число. Например: 12345

Comment: Переменных нужно десять.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном случае проще всего будет преобразовать число в список цифр и сравнить его длину с длиной множества цифр. Множество (`set`) в Python может содержать только уникальные элементы. Если конструктору `set(...)` подать на вход список элементов с дупликатами, то на выходе мы получим множество, состоящее из уникальных элементов:

```
In [103]: set('11112222223')
Out[103]: {'1', '2', '3'}
```

Решение:

```
In [99]: N=262

In [100]: s=list(str(N))

In [101]: print(len(set(s)) < len(s))
True
```

если нужно напечатать YES / NO:

```
In [102]: print('YES' if len(set(s)) < len(s) else 'NO')
YES
```